# nodejs 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error for high traffic

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am using `nodejs` `0.12.2` and `express.js 4` and `async` `waterfall` flow for handling synchronous functionality.
On database site using `redis` on `Elasticache` and `Dynamodb`.
I am using `pm2` module for threading and deployment.
And code is running on `Centos6` on `AWS` `ec2` behind `ELB`, also using autoscaling for `ELB`.
My code working perfectly for low traffic of 200 request/min but when I increase traffic on server to 10000 request/min, I'm getting `504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT` error.

My Sample code is as follows.

`routes/idex.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var async = require('async');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');
// other require variables 

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    try {
        var rd = JSON.parse(query.hit);
        if (rd === false && typeof rd !== "object" && rd === null) {
            next();
        }
    } catch (e) {

    }

    async.waterfall([
        function (next) {
            next(null, rd);
        },
        func1,
        func2
    ], function (err, result) {

    });

    response["d"] = "d";
    res.json(response);
}); // eof route
module.exports = router;

function func1(rd, next) {
    var gd = {
        var1: rd.var1
    };



    gd.var2 = false;
    common.callback1(gd.var2, function (x) {
        gd.var2 = session_id || false;
        if (gd.var2 === false || !gd.var2) {
            common.setVar(varData);
        }
        next(null, gd);
    });

} // EOF func1


function func2(gd, next) {

    // looping synchronously
    async.eachLimit(gd.vars4, 1, function (var4, callback) {

        async.waterfall([
            function (inner_callback) {
                common.cb1(domain, function (si) {
                    inner_callback(null, si);
                });

            },
            function (si, inner_callback) {
                common.cb2(si, sub_domain, function (si) {
                    inner_callback(null, si);
                });

            },
        ],
                function (err, si) {
                    callback();
                });

    }); // eof for loop
    next(null, "true");
}
```

Comment: Can you include a trace of the error?

Comment: @lxe there is no error for single requests, also no errors in `console`
all errors are getting to end users on browser, and I can see them in `ELB` monitoring.

Comment: Are you using a web server front end to node?

Comment: @datasage no, I'm using nodejs for `data collection`, and using `elastic load balancer`  for load balancing

Comment: In that case the 504 errors originate from the ELB. What does the CPU load look like for 10k requests? How many instances are you running?

Comment: @datasage I'm using autoscaling so CPU usage always remains low, I'm using fixed 2 instances and auto scaled instances when cpu usage goes up.
I'm roughly running 5 `c3` instances for 10k requests.

Comment: Are you scaling before or after starting the test? Some requests may fail if you increase load too quickly, since starting new instances take time.

Comment: I'm autoscaling after requests started increasing, I've waited till  to load balancer to add  instances and cool down.

Comment: Elastic load balancers themselves cannot react to really sudden increases. Is this a gradual growth, or are you going from almost nothing to 10,000 immediately? Behind the scenes, the load balancer is running on ec2 instances also.

Comment: FYI async.eachLimit is not synchronous. So you will call next() and proceed from func2 before the asynchronous logic is executed. Also I am not sure what happens when you redefine next in the first line of the waterfall call.

Comment: @CargoMeister I'm increasing traffic suddenly but I'm waiting for elb to react properly ignoring initial errors.  @Plato `eachLimit` is deliberately async, it should return to user instead of waiting. and `next` in first  anonymous function passing values for rd to func1.

Comment: @SandipPingle Did you ever figure out a solution to the problem above? I am facing similar issues with node/express/AWS combination. I get 504 exactly after a minute. I tried setting request.SetTimeout to a longer period but it's useless... Any help is much appreciated.